# Mongo DB Storing References

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling, database

In a Mongo environment it is beneficial to embed data in documents.

so for example an Employees document:

```
{
    {
         userid: 'someid',
         username: 'user1'
         isManager: true,
         subordinates: [
             {
                  userid: 'anotherid',
                  username: 'user2',
                  isManager: false
             }
         ],
         officeLocation: {
             officeId: 'someofficeid',
             officeName: 'Some Office'
         }
     },
     {
          userid: 'anotherid',
          username: 'user2',
          isManager: false,
          officeLocation: {
             officeId: 'someotherofficeid',
             officeName: 'Some Other Office'
          }
     }
}
```

And the office document:

```
{
     {
          officeid: 'someofficeid',
          officeName: 'Some Office'
     },
     {
          officeid: 'someotherofficeid',
          officeName: 'Some Other Office'
     }
}
```

So lets assume that someone in the company decides that they don't like the name `Some Other Office` and they want to change it to `Some Cool Office`.

When they make the change in the office document how do we know to update all the embedded `Some Other Office` in the employee document as well?

It seems that every time that you take a piece of data from one document and embed it into an object in another document that the link between the two gets broken and then you have to write separate queries to update the data in all the different spots that you embedded that object into.

I like the idea of embedded documents rather than storing references, but without some kind of 2 way data-binding it seems impractical when it comes to updating information.

Is there any way that I would be able to bind the data two ways or is there an easier way to go about modeling my data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It remainds me about the traditional RDBMS systems when you model to normalize/denormalize an information. I'm not sure about the binding, but, if you need the "single true" for an information, the better way is never having the information stored in two different places. So, in your case, it may be better to store the Office information into a separated document and just link it by Id.